# Efficiently find neighbors on multiple dimensions and calculate sum of values based on proximity

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am tasked with finding the total value of all elements within a variable distance of a central element. The elements are arranged using 3 dimensions (columns in my data). Each element has a unique location given the 3 dimensions (and has a unique-id).

I have a working version that does what I want, however it is terribly slow. I am using itertuples, finding the value per tuple using a subset dataframe, apply(np.isclose), and I set the value with .at (see code below).

The problem is not so much the function of my code as it is the scalability. Since I want to set a variable distance to measure, and I want to calculate this value for each row, it ends up iterating nrows x ndistances, and currently each iteration takes 1.7 seconds (my data has >25,000 rows, I estimated ~12 hours per each distance I try).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Example of data structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19], 
                          'x':[-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                          'y':[2,1,0,2,1,0,-1,2,1,0,-1,-2,1,0,-1,-2,0,-1,-2], 
                          'z':[0,1,2,-1,0,1,2,-2,-1,0,1,2,-2,-1,0,1,-2,-1,0], 
                          'val':[0,0,0,1,0,0,6,3,7,11,0,0,14,18,10,4,20,15,2]})
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
# The 'val' column can have any non-negative whole number, I've just picked some randomly.
```

'Working' code so far:

```
n = 0  #Initial distance
while n < 3:  #This part allows me to set my distance range
    df['n{0}'.format(n)] = np.nan  #create a column for the new values
    for row in df.itertuples():
        valsum = df[(df['x'].apply(np.isclose, b=row.x, atol=n)) & 
                    (df['y'].apply(np.isclose, b=row.y, atol=n)) & 
                    (df['z'].apply(np.isclose, b=row.z, atol=n))].val.sum()
        df.at[row.Index, 'n{0}'.format(n)] = valsum
    n += 1
```

Current / Desired output:

```
    x   y   z   val n0  n1  n2
id                          
1   -2  2   0   0   0   1   22
2   -2  1   1   0   0   0   25
3   -2  0   2   0   0   6   17
4   -1  2   -1  1   1   11  54
5   -1  1   0   0   0   19  70
6   -1  0   1   0   0   17  57
7   -1  -1  2   6   6   6   31
8   0   2   -2  3   3   25  74
9   0   1   -1  7   7   54  99
10  0   0   0   11  11  46  111
11  0   -1  1   0   0   31  73
12  0   -2  2   0   0   10  33
13  1   1   -2  14  14  62  99
14  1   0   -1  18  18  95  105
15  1   -1  0   10  10  60  107
16  1   -2  1   4   4   16  66
17  2   0   -2  20  20  67  100
18  2   -1  -1  15  15  65  101
19  2   -2  0   2   2   31  80
```

I know that having the 'n0' column is equal to 'val' column, because the search distance is 0, but I wanted to hopefully show what I am looking for. The sum of all the items in the val column is 111, which is the same when (x,y,z) = (0,0,0). This is because (0,0,0) is the center of my data in this example, and therefore having a distance of 2 captures all of the elements.  I'd like to do this for a bandwidth of distances, say, 5-10.

My ultimate question is: How can I do this but faster / more efficiently?

Comment: your `n+= 1` needs to be out of the for loop otherwise you don't get your current answer.

Comment: Your distance criteria defines Manhattan distance, rather than Euclidean (straight-line) distance. Is that intended?

Comment: @Ben Pap you're right, I'll fix it. It is correct in my file

Comment: @peter Leimbigler I'm not sure I understand what you mean (I am unfamiliar with Manhattan distance) however I am fairly confident this is correct as presented.

Comment: @zoupah, understood, thanks! Maybe I can answer in a way that can easily adapt to either distance metric.

Comment: Apologies: I mistakenly wrote that the logic in the question describes Manhattan distance, when in fact it defines Chebyshev distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance). Sorry if this misled anyone down the wrong path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding nearest neighbours within k-dimensional space is a classic case for the k-d tree data structure ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)). Scikit-learn has a flexible implementation ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)) which I use below, since the conditional logic used in your question seems to define the Chebyshev distance metric ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)), which scikit-learn supports natively. SciPy's `cKDTree` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html), [C++ source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src)) supports only the Euclidean (L2) distance metric, but is optimized for it, and thus might be faster.

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19], 
                   'x':[-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                   'y':[2,1,0,2,1,0,-1,2,1,0,-1,-2,1,0,-1,-2,0,-1,-2], 
                   'z':[0,1,2,-1,0,1,2,-2,-1,0,1,2,-2,-1,0,1,-2,-1,0], 
                   'val':[0,0,0,1,0,0,6,3,7,11,0,0,14,18,10,4,20,15,2]})
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)


from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

# Build k-d tree with the Chebyshev metric, AKA L-infinity
tree = KDTree(df[['x', 'y', 'z']].values, metric='chebyshev')

for radius in [0, 1, 2]:
    # Populate new column with placeholder integer
    df[f'n{radius}'] = -1
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        coords = row[['x', 'y', 'z']].values.reshape(1, -1)
        idx = tree.query_radius(coords, r=radius)[0]
        df.loc[i, f'n{radius}'] = df.iloc[idx]['val'].sum()

df
    x  y  z  val  n0  n1   n2
id                           
1  -2  2  0    0   0   1   22
2  -2  1  1    0   0   0   25
3  -2  0  2    0   0   6   17
4  -1  2 -1    1   1  11   54
5  -1  1  0    0   0  19   70
6  -1  0  1    0   0  17   57
7  -1 -1  2    6   6   6   31
8   0  2 -2    3   3  25   74
9   0  1 -1    7   7  54   99
10  0  0  0   11  11  46  111
11  0 -1  1    0   0  31   73
12  0 -2  2    0   0  10   33
13  1  1 -2   14  14  62   99
14  1  0 -1   18  18  95  105
15  1 -1  0   10  10  60  107
16  1 -2  1    4   4  16   66
17  2  0 -2   20  20  67  100
18  2 -1 -1   15  15  65  101
19  2 -2  0    2   2  31   80
```

Comment: Wow, it's an hour I was scratching my head because I could not reproduce OP expected results with manhattan distance.

Comment: @Valentino, I mistakenly thought that the OP's logic described Manhattan distance, but realized later that it's actually Chebyshev distance!

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Thank you for this (and for point me to Chebyshev distance)! I still need to work through how it works but I can already say it is performing so much faster. It finished 1000 rows in the time my code could do 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution which does not require additional packages.

Thse are functions which define a distance between two points `a` and `b`. Here are shown Euclidean, Manhattan and Chebyshev distance (credits to [@Peter Leimbigler answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56486031/10426037) who recognized that the last one is the one used by the OP). `a` and `b` are assumed to be a 3-length list. You can use one of them (or even define other customized distance functions).

```
def euclidean(a, b):
    """euclidean distance"""
    return np.sqrt((a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2 + (a[2] - b[2])**2) 

def manhattan(a, b):
    """manhattan distance"""
    return abs(a[0] - b[0]) + abs(a[1] - b[1]) + abs(a[2] - b[2])

def cebyshev(a, b):
    """cebyshev distance"""
    return max(abs(a[0] - b[0]), abs(a[1] - b[1]), abs(a[2] - b[2]))
```

The following function returns for a point `point` the sum of the values of the `val` column in the dataframe `data` (this is your dataframe) whose coordinates are closer than a distance `d`. `func` is the function used to calculate the distance (one of those before).

```
def getclosesum(data, point, d, func):
    dists = data.apply(lambda x : func(x, point), axis=1)
    return data['val'].loc[dists <= d].sum()
```

Finally you can calculate your column by using `df.apply`:

```
for n in range(3):
    df['n{0}'.format(n)] = df.apply(lambda x : getclosesum(df, x, n, cebyshev), axis=1)
```

Using your sample dataframe, on my machine this code takes 0.155 seconds to do the job, while your original code takes 0.233 seconds.
So this is faster than your solution, but not so fast as the code provided by @Peter Leimbigler (I bet `scikit` is more optimized).

Comment: Thanks for this! I was originally trying to use a distance-function like this but couldn't figure anything out (probably because I am too narrow minded in what 'distance' can mean). This generally uses the same 'method' of determining distance I used, but is much faster computationally if I understand correctly. Whereas @Peter Leimbigler is utilizing a function in sklearn that actually allows for distance to be quickly generalized, I think. (I'm going to be spending my weekend making sure I understand all this...)

Answer (score 2):

This solution also uses KDTrees (from scipy library).

In your code and the previous answers, when the loop is calculating the result for radius = 3, it is repeating the work that has already been done for radius = 0, 1,
and 2.

The code below does all the calculations with one pass through the nodes.  Define a max distance and a number of range bins. Find all node pairs with the max distance and use `np.digitize()` to map the actual distance to a range bin.  Add 'val' to the mapped range bin.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree

# define the range and number of range bins 
# this example defines 3 bins: 0.0 - 1.0; 1.0 - 2.0; 2.0 - 3.0
max_distance = 3.0
nbins = 3
bin_range = 0.0, max_distance
bins = np.linspace(*bin_range, nbins+1)[1:]

# build a KDTree and generate a sparse matrix of node pairs
# that have a max distance of bin_range[-1]
tree = KDTree(df[['x','y','z']])
dist = tree.sparse_distance_matrix(tree, bin_range[-1])

# one row per node, one column per range bin
sums = np.zeros((len(df), nbins))

# for each pair of nodes, map the range to the bin index and add
# the value of the second node to mapped bin for the 1st node 
for (j,k),d in dist.items():
    sums[j][np.digitize(d, bins)] += df['val'][k+1]
```

For each node the array `sums` contains a row with the sums for the binned ranges.  For example, the first column contains the sum of the vals for nodes with distance < 1, the second column for nodes between 1 and 2, and the third column for nodes between 2 and 3.  You can accumulate across the columns to get the same results as your table.

```
sums

array([[ 0.,  1., 21.],
       [ 0.,  0., 25.],
       [ 0.,  6., 11.],
       [ 1., 10., 43.],
       [ 0., 19., 51.],
       [ 0., 17., 40.],
       [ 6.,  0., 25.],
       [ 3., 22., 49.],
       [ 7., 47., 45.],
       [11., 35., 65.],
       [ 0., 31., 42.],
       [ 0., 10., 23.],
       [14., 48., 37.],
       [18., 77., 10.],
       [10., 50., 47.],
       [ 4., 12., 50.],
       [20., 47., 33.],
       [15., 50., 36.],
       [ 2., 29., 49.]])
```

Comment: Very cool! I would note this is dependent on the index numbering in the last step. For anyone finding this in the future, this answer works if you reset your index and change the [k+1] at the end to just be [k]:

df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
...
for (j,k),d in dist.items():
    sums[j][np.digitize(d, bins)] += df['val'][k]

This produces an array of lists that then needs to be summed up and added to the df appropriately. Do you have a fast way to do this? The calculation is maybe faster than the accepted answer, but trying to add those values to my df made it slower overall.

Comment: @zoupah Convert `sums` to a DataFrame with the same index as `df`, like so:  `sdf = pd.DataFrame(data=sums, index=df.index)`, then you can concatenate the two dataframes:  `big_df = pd.concat([df, sdf], axis = 1)`.